# CSS menu not displaying in IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have an issue with the following CSS menu in IE 8 it will not display - it shows a default list - not the menu as shown in other browsers (http://interclub.org.uk)

Please advice any corrections or support or alternatives for the CSS or document to display in IE 8

HTML Doc Type:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

HTML for including script:

```
<link href="../default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

CSS used for menu:

```
#menu {
float: right;
width: 1200px;
height: 15px;
padding: 0px 10px 0px 20px;
}

#menu ul {
float: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 10px 0px 0px 50px;
list-style: none;
line-height: normal;


#menu li {
float: left;
}

#menu a {
display: block;
margin-left: 1px;
padding: 7px 8px 7px 8px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Passion One', sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: lighter;
color: #fff;
background-color:#009900
}

#menu a:hover, #menu .current_page_item a {
text-decoration: none;
background: #A0190A;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
border-radius: 5px;
color: #fff;
}
```

Menu HTML DIV

```
<div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../draw.htm" accesskey="1" title="">Draw &amp; Results</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://blog.interclub.org.uk" accesskey="9" title="">the 19th</a></li>
            <li><a href="../userarea/contact.php" accesskey="2" title="">Team Directory</a></li>
            <li><a href="../userarea/submit-result.php" accesskey="2" title="">Submit Result</a></li>
            <li><a href="../rules.htm" accesskey="4" title="">Rules</a></li>
            <li><a href="../faq.htm" accesskey="5" title="">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="../supporting-junior-golf.htm" accesskey="3" title="">Supporting Junior Golf</a></li>
            <li><a href="../about.htm" accesskey="2" title="">About the Comp</a></li>
            <li><a href="../contactus.htm" accesskey="6" title="">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://ladies.interclub.org.uk" accesskey="7" title=""><img src="../images/ladieslogo.png" alt="" width="16" height="16" align="top" />Ladies Inter-Club</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Browser support**

- `border-radius` is [not supported by IE8 or earlier](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius).
- `box-shadow` is [not supported by IE8 or earlier](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow).

**HTML**

Validating the HTML revealed [42 errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Finterclub.org.uk%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). The main issues might be caused by invalid HTML. Different browsers react differently to bad HTML.

There appears to be an extra `</div>` tag at the end of the header. If IE8 reacts to this by creating a different DOM structure, then the CSS selectors for the header might not get applied.

Also, a lot of the image tags have an extra double-quote character. That might cause unpredictable results as well.

Comment: have removed these elements - still not showing any closer to expected

Comment: When I ran it earlier using IE10 in IE8 standards, the only issues were with `border-radius` and `box-shadow`. Trying it now in IETester, I see that the styling of the header appears to be almost completely lost. Is that what you're seeing? Either way it might be helpful if you could add an IE8 screenshot to the question above.

Comment: YEs i am seeing the complete loss of the styling in IE - will try and capture screen shot (to describe - in IE the menu shows as a list to the right, not as a menu bar)

Comment: @BlairCrawford: Then I'm seeing exactly what you're seeing. There appears to be some invalid HTML. See the validation link added above.

Comment: will look into the errors (sorry my bad html there) - Thanks for link

Comment: @BlairCrawford: There appears to be one too many `</div>` tags at the end of the header.

Comment: etrax </div> should now be removed

Comment: I still see the extra </div> on the live website. It's one of the 3 </div> tags before <div id="wrapper">. I even see the last one highlighted in red when I do a view source in Firefox. And a lot of the image tags have an extra double-quote character. Trying viewing the source in Firefox; it also shows the img tags highlighted in red.

Comment: @BlairCrawford: It looks fine now. BTW, it's okay to put the `border-radius` and `box-shadow` back in. They won't work in IE8, but that's not what was breaking the header. The main reason I mentioned them is because I thought that was the only problem you were having.

Comment: IE issue was resolved by fixing the poorly constructed image tags, which had extra double quote inside them - Thanks for the help Matt - Noted re the css styles.

Answer (score 0):

try this jquery with library 1.4.2 for border-radius work

```
// This adds 'placeholder' to the items listed in the jQuery .support object. 
jQuery(function() {
   jQuery.support.placeholder = false;
   test = document.createElement('input');
   if('placeholder' in test) jQuery.support.placeholder = true;
});
// This adds placeholder support to browsers that wouldn't otherwise support it. 
$(function() {
   if(!$.support.placeholder) { 
      var active = document.activeElement;
      $(':text').focus(function () {
         if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
            $(this).val('').removeClass('hasPlaceholder');
         }
      }).blur(function () {
         if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))) {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('hasPlaceholder');
         }
      });
      $(':text').blur();
      $(active).focus();
      $('form:eq(0)').submit(function () {
         $(':text.hasPlaceholder').val('');
      });
   }
});
```